# How to remember the time for prayer and to fight the Satan whispering to us?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, imaan

I have a problem lately, I don't know why I keep missing my Isyaa' prayer. It's been almost 2 weeks now. I want to keep praying and pray to Allah and I keep forgetting or just jump into bed and sleep.

One time, I made my wudu and got ready to pray but then I sat on my bed for a while and dozed off, the next thing I know it's already Subuh pray time.

How to strengthen our faith and to fight satan?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fight the satan is the remembrance of Allah(Dhikr).

As Allah says in this Ayah:

## "الَّذِينَ آمَنُواْ وَتَطْمَئِنُّ قُلُوبُهُم بِذِكْرِ اللَّهِ أَلاَ بِذِكْرِ اللَّهِ تَطْمَئِنُّ الْقُلُوبُ"

[image: Remembrance of Allah]

While you are waiting for the prayer time you can fill your time reading Quran,  Worshiping Allah(Tasbih) and seeking his forgiveness(Istighfar) and especially reading the Quran, it helps you to keep your heart filled up with faith and to maintain this faith sturdy and firm.

Another solution is to keep praying(Nafilah) until it's the prayer time as Allah says in this two Ayahat:

## " يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اسْتَعِينُوا بِالصَّبْرِ وَالصَّلَاةِ"

[image: Patience and Prayer] [image: Patience and Prayer]

***Note:** You can always set a reminder in your phone if you are very tired.*

Answer (score 0):

By praying [Ishraq](http://ourpurposeoflife.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-perform-salat-al-duha-and-salat.html) Salah in the morning after sunrise. From a hadith, we come to know that if we pray  Salat al-Ishraq, Allah will help us with our responsibilities throughout the day among which our Fardh prayers are one of them.

Also remember Allah as much as you can.

Having an after noon nap should also help.